# Force refresh view in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Aura, we can do

```
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

to cause standard components to update.

How can we do an equivalent in LWC because sfdx refuses to publish .js code with $A in it saying the usage is disallowed in LWC?

For now i tricked it with

```
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
```

but that is obviously less than ideal....

Comment: What is your use case, as when do you want to refresh the view, viz., editing or deleting a record? Are you using standard LDS or `@wire` decorators, or you are using custom apex methods?

Comment: @JayantDas i have my component that creates related records of user's drag-n-drop actions; on the same page layout i have a related list (standard LWC component provided by SalesForce). I want related list to refresh when the user interacts with my component.

Comment: Standard LWC related list? Do you mean the standard related list component in LEX? While the approach you have may work, but an ideal way for this would be to wrap your LWC in an Aura Component, utilize events for communication and let the Aura Component refresh the view.

Comment: @JayantDas yes i do mean the standard related list component in Lightning Experience. Having an Aura wrapper just to do refresh seems a bit backwards. I would've thought that the platform provided some interop functionality for actually talking to other components on the page :/

Comment: Wrapping it within Aura is kind of interop here. Unfortunately there’s no direct 1-1 replacement for quite a few Aura features at least at this point of time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to find [an answer on the Developer Docs forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XjwnQAC) for a work-around. I was surprised how challenging it was to find a solution in the Salesforce LWC docs, so I'm not sure if this is the recommended approach, but it's the best I've been able to find!

You will need to import the `updateRecord` method from the `lightning/uiRecordApi`. Then, you can call this `updateRecord()` function in your lwc javascript file whenever you want your detail record page (i.e. Account Detail Page) to refresh.

In the following example, I have a lwc that lives on my lightning detail page on the Account record (i.e. as a side-bar component). In the example, my lwc calls a handleClick method that imperatively calls an `updateAccount()` method in my Apex Controller Class. In the callback method, I update the Account Detail record using the `updateRecord()` function.

**Import Statement:**

`import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';`

**Function:**

`updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId } });`

**Example:**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import updateAccount from '@salesforce/apex/ApexControllerClass.updateAccount;

export default class lightning-web-component-example extends LightningElement {

     @api recordId;

     handleClick(){

          // Call Apex Method imperatively to update Account record
          updateAccount({accountId: this.recordId})
               .then( result => {
          
                    if (result) {
                         // Refresh Account Detail Page
                         updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId }})
                    }

               })
     }
}
```

Comment: Note: this is performing an actual DML operation on the record, not just "updating" the local client. This will mark the record as "Last Modified By" the viewer, which may not be ideal.

Comment: Received and error: Invalid recordInput when trying to follow this approach

Comment: People still seem to be coming to my question - this is the answer we used and it has worked well enough for the past few years.

Comment: @zaitsman your probably wanna have a look at latest Spring 23 functionality
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/396434/19118

Answer (score 40):

Starting in [Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm), you'll be able to use `getRecordNotifyChange()` function to refresh your record page from a lightning web component.

`getRecordNotifyChange` is working almost the same way `force:refreshView` did, except it takes a list of `recordId` which makes it a little bit more flexible:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import apexUpdateRecord from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.apexUpdateRecord';
     
export default class NotifyRecordChangeExample extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
     
  // Wire a record.
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ... })
  record;
     
  async handler() {
    // Update the record via Apex.
    await apexUpdateRecord(this.recordId);
    // Notify LDS that you've changed the record outside its mechanisms.
    getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
  }
}
```

Comment: getRecordNotifyChange is nice but it doesn't seem to work for new records. I'm adding new records via a LWC and can't get the related list count to update to reflect the new records added. End users are getting confused because it doesn't look like records have been added to the list.

Comment: I agree, Salesforce is aware of this limitation but I don't know what's the roadmap for it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not refreshes the related list when we create a new child record from parent detail page via a LWC component. Probably this works only for current record.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work with all related list, can you list here which one doesn't work for you ?

Comment: I don't have related list, I have a flexi page with conditional rendering of components based on record attributes. When I use Aura action button with refreshView, the flexi page is refreshed and displays correctly the needed attributes. But when I use getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]); it never refreshes the flexi page

Comment: I think getRecordNotifyChange() will let Lightning Data Service knows that the records was updated, so if the components on the flexipage don't use LDS that won't work, unless they are updated to listen to LDS changes.

Comment: I have tried to add getRecord() method from LDS to retrieve and display the status field, which has changed, but it still doesn't work in my case. Only when I add standard record detail component to the page, it works, but my clients desire to remove record detail component.

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a new question on StackExchange with the details, I think it's supposed to work.

Comment: Use eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
It will update related lists.

Comment: It works, but it's not recommended and won't work with LWS

Comment: Yeah well, it does the job and nothing else works, so...

Answer (score 24):

Adding information from comments.

As of today, there's no 1-1 mapping of Aura vs. LWC events/interfaces. While the approach you have in there may work, but I will personally not recommend it to use that way.

As understood from your comments, you have a LWC on a Lighting page in LEX along with other standard components, viz., related list. And that upon updates on the LWC, you want the standard related list to be refreshed. My approach here would have been to *wrap* the LWC in an Aura Component, send an event to the Aura Component and then utilize `force:refreshView` on the Aura Component.

This may look like a *boiler-plate* approach, but because you can compose a LWC within an Aura Component and can communicate with events, this approach would be the *safer* route.

Your overall implementation could look as:

```
<aura:component>
    <-- this is the LWC -->
    <c:myLWCComponent onrecordChange="{!c.refreshView}" />
</aura:component>
```

And then in the LWC, you raise the event once you have the records updated:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('recordChange'));
```

And then in your Aura JS Controller, you handle the event:

```
refreshView: function(component, event) {
    // refresh the view
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
},
```

Comment: Standard SF components are made using LWC, they respond to refreshView event, SF might allow this in future release

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Hopefully yes. That would eliminate the need of this approach.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The parent Aura component doesn't catch the event fired from the LWC. Do you only have to add the event's name preceded by `on` inside the tag used in the parent Aura component?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Yes, you will need to prefix the event name with `on` to be able to handle that event. You can find more details on the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components).

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, by habit, I set the name with an uppercase letter. No wonder it didn't work. My event, named `closeCheckInModal`, was written in the Aura component as `onCloseCheckInModal` (notice the first uppercase "C"?). Thank very much for this answer. 

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Glad that you found this helpful. I just realized that I have the same issue in the answer here :). Will update it to reflect the correct `on...` handler.

Comment: @JayantDas - is this solution still the only available one, or is it possible now to do from my LWC?

Comment: @ItaiShmida You could possibly use the approach as in other answers but I am not aware of anything direct equivalent of `force:refreshView` for LWC.

Comment: For those still coming here - yes, this does work fine, but we are in a managed package with hundreds of components so I didn't take this route as it is an incredibly amount of extra effort to maintain this just for the functionality. `updateRecord()` did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Spring 23 update. Refresh view event is now available for lwc. :)

```
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  // a button click or programmatically
  onRefresh() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
  }
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/01/lwc-enhancements-for-developers-learn-moar-spring-23

Comment: This should be the top answer now

Comment: It's a beta feature though.

Comment: @zaitsman beta can be used in producation... so makes much of difference

Comment: If I fire this after a flow in a quick action, how can I listen and trigger my own logic in a custom lwc somewhere else on the page?

Answer (score 4):

You can import and use `refreshApex`.

```
    import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

    // If you want to refresh @wire property

    @wire(accountData) accts;

    methodAfterWhichYouWantToRefresh(){
//your code .....
    .............
    ........
       refreshApex(this.accts);
    } 

    // If you have Imperative Method

    handleLoad() {
            getContactList()
                .then(result => {
                    this.contacts = result;
                    this.error = undefined;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.contacts = undefined;
                });
        }

    methodAfterWhichYouWantToRefresh(){
       //your code .....
    .............
    ........

       refreshApex(this.handleLoad());
    }
```

above is just example not full code...

Comment: A full example can be found at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record

Answer (score 1):

I used **combination of Apex and Navigation**

- Update same record in apex method (just update DML, no field values changed)
- When response is returned, navigate on record detail page

```js
navigateToViewAccountPage() { 
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
   type: 'standard__recordPage', 
   attributes: { recordId: this.recordId, objectApiName: 'Account', actionName: 
   'view' }, 
   }); 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause the whole page to reload?