# Lightning Knowledge component is not refreshed when the case changed programatically

Tags: lightning-web-components, servicecloud, lightning-data-service, lightning-knowledge

In the detail page below, the **standard** Knowledge component is properly refreshed when I change the "Verbatim (English Language)" field through the UI.

[image]

However, if I change the value of "Verbatim (English Language)" field using Lightning Data Services the Knowledge component is not refreshed.

**Does anybody knows how to have the Knowledge component refreshed when Case record fields are changed programatically?**

Below is the source code I am using to change the "English Verbatim" field value. It's API name is actually `Subject`, the default Case field.

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CASE_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Id';
import CASE_SUBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';

export default class CustomKnowledge extends LightningElement
{
    @api recordId;

    handleAddVerbatimClick()
    {
        updateRecord(this.getRecordInput('Knowledge Article'));
    }

    handleRemoveVerbatimClick()
    {
        updateRecord(this.getRecordInput(''));
    }

    getRecordInput(subject)
    {
        return {
            fields: {
                [CASE_ID_FIELD.fieldApiName]: this.recordId,
                [CASE_SUBJECT.fieldApiName]: subject
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the knowledge a custom component you have built?

Comment: No. It's the standard component.

Comment: try firing refreshView event post update? [eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc)

Comment: Thank you @PranayJaiswal. I tried but it hasn't worked.

Comment: update record is async process, did you fire after update record has completed?

Comment: yes. I fired it from `Promise.then()`

Comment: Might be a bug in the standard component.