# When Navigating to a standard record page from a lightning web component the related list on the record page has not been updated

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, related-list

I use a lighting web component to create multiple related records linked to a parent record. After this is completed I use the NavigationMixin to redirect back to the parent record. I am successfully redirected but the related list does not show the newly created records and I need to refresh the page again before they appear.

Is there anyway I can force the page to be refreshed or to display these new related records when I am initially redirected? Below is the sample code of the final redirect

```
navigateToParentRecord(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force refresh view in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc). Check the answer by Fabien Taillon

Comment: Thanks so much Rahul, the new Winter '21 function of getRecordNotifyChange() did the trick. Great.