# Refresh a lwc component on record creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I would like to understand if there is any alternative to
`force:refreshView` in lightning-web-components.

I have a small component embedded in Account Detail page which creates a new Contact. My requirement is to refresh only the component, and not the entire page, once one Contact is created.

Please note: I do not want to use, `window.reload()`, as it will refresh the entire page, and that is not a good user experience.

No data is getting updated once the record is updated. Just the form needs to get refreshed, so I am not sure if I can use `getRecordNotifyChange()`.

I would like to understand if there is something which does the exact same thing as `force:refreshView`, does in Aura.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force refresh view in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc)

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. Thanks.