# How can I refresh a LWC in connectedCallback function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer

I have a LWC that is loaded using the connectedCallback function. It loads and displays record data correctly, however I added a delete button next to each record and I'm having trouble refreshing the component after a record is deleted. I can't use `RefreshApex` because I'm not using `@wire` decorator. I tried using `$A.get('e. force:refreshView').fire()` with no success. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try calling the connectedCallback() method after the delete function in js returns success. If you are calling the Apex method imperative from a different function you could call that function too.

This should ideally change your track variable value and would refresh your component screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Why you should never use eval](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-eval)

[Force refresh view in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc)

If the above two haven't perturbed you from using eval, AND because you mentioned wanting to use e.force:refreshView event, here's the snippet using eval

Edited for clarity.

`eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");`

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is welcome, but I do not understand how your post answers the question originally asked. I do not see where *sfdev* (OP) or *Ajay* (other answerer) made mention of `eval`. It could just be my ignorance. If this answer is, indeed, meant for this question, please [edit] it to better explain *why* it answers it. But if this answer was meant for some other question, please delete it from this one.

Comment: Hey there, so from what I thought the ask was (and forgive me if I misinterpreted it), was that they wanted to refresh the component/page in LWC similar to how $A.get('e. force:refreshView').fire() works in aura. To achieve that functionality, I provided that aura snippet wrapped in eval. 

Again sorry if I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Ahh, OK. I originally understood your answer as an answer only on why not to use `eval`. I see now that you were essentially saying, "You can use `eval` to achieve what you want, but be forewarned that there are reasons why you might not want to do that."

Comment: @Moonpie exactly