# Refresh related list after creating a record via LWC quick action

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-recordeditform, modal

I built a screen action LWC that uses `lightning-record-edit-form` and `lightning-input-field` to create a new record. The quick action is placed on a parent record page and adds a related child record to the parent record. The quick action can create a record but after closing the modal, the related list shows the old information. I'd like to refresh the related list after closing the modal but don't know how to implement it.

I already tried `getRecordNotifyChange()` but it seems to be only applicable when editing a record, not when creating a record.

I also have tried `updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId }})` seeing the following question but it seems to be only applicable when creating a record by an Apex method, not the `lightning-record-edit-form` feature:
[Force refresh view in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc/251370#251370)

Can anybody help to solve this issue?
Thanks.

My related markup:

```
<lightning-quick-action-panel header="Create a Question">
    <lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name="question__c"
        onsuccess={close_modal}
        >
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field  field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_xx-small" label="cancel" onclick={handleReset}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_xx-small" type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</lightning-quick-action-panel>
```

My JS function:

```
close_modal() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Record is created',
            variant: 'success'
        })
    );   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use [the RefreshView API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html) now. Import `RefreshView` from `lightning/refresh` and dispatch that event.

```js
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
  method() {
    // this will tell the view to refresh its contents
    this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
  }
}
```